# jquery append new select box on click

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to append a new standardized select box option every time I click on my paragraph, for example my paragraph is written as below:

`<p id="newsublevel">Click here to add a new sub level to your navigation</p>`

Once I click this I want my jQuery code to add a new select box under the existing in the div called maincontent(which is a class not an id). the jQuery I have now has a syntax warning but I haven't got much experience in this area, is there anyone who knows what I am doing wrong?

by default I have this on my add.html page

```
<h2 class="sitemaphead">Sitemap</h2>
<p>Add a sub level to About.</a></p>

<select>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
</select>

<p id"newsublevel">Click here to add another sub level</p>
```

in my jQuery I have the following:

```
    $("#newsublevel").click(function() {
$(".maincontent").append('<select>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
</select>');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assignment of `value="Home"`

you code becomes

```
$("#newsublevel").click(function () {
    $(".maincontent").append('<select><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option></select>');
});
```

and HTML

```
<p id="newsublevel">
```

Comment: oops my bad so simple, can't believe I missed something so simple. thank you

Comment: say if I wanted to then remove this this select option on click by clicking a link i.e. `<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>` how would I do this I have assigned a class to to the select option and inserted this into my jQuery `$(".remove").click(function() {$(".navoptions").remove(".hello");});` however this doesn't remove anything, class navoptions has now replaced maincontent so that the select appends below the default select box

Comment: @gutigrewal make a new question that will help us to understand better what you want .

Comment: have done click here for [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784879/jquery-remove-function-not-doing-anything) thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
<p id"newsublevel">
```

**With**

```
<p id = "newsublevel">
-----^^^^----
```

Answer (score 0):

Add \ at the end of every string line like this

```
$(".maincontent").append('<select>\
<option value="Home">Home</option>\
<option value="Home">Home</option>\
<option value="Home">Home</option>\
<option value="Home">Home</option>\
<option value="Home">Home</option>\
<option value="Home">Home</option>\
<option value="Home">Home</option>\
</select>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ur html...
value**-**"Home"
and
**id"**newsublevel"

To do this, u can try:

```
$('#newsublevel').live('click', function() {
    $('select').clone().appendTo('.maincontent')
})
```