# jQuery remove function not doing anything

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function in my jquery that will append a new select class on the click of a link. 
What I now what to do is remove this class on the click of a button in case a user decides not to use this select function.

My append function works like so:

```
$("#newsublevel").click(function() {
        $(".navoptions").append('<br/><select class="hello"><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Home">Home</option></select><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
    });
```

I have this on my remove function however this is not working at all:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
        $(".hello").remove();
    });
```

How can I effectively remove the select box that the hyperlink is referring to? I've tried about two different ways to remove this without success, any ideas?

add.html

```
<div class="maincontent">
<h2 class="sitemaphead">Sitemap</h2>
<p>Add a sub level to About.</a></p>
<div class="navoptions">
<select>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
<option value-"Home">Home</option>
</select>
</div>
<p id=""><a href="#" id="newsublevel">Click here</a> to add another sub level</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(".navoptions").on('click','.remove',function() {
     $(".hello").remove();
});
```

Comment: Correct. Delegation is the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Won't that remove all selects if he's added more than one select http://jsfiddle.net/QBqWP/1/

Comment: @Anton check --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QBqWP/2/ .In your case it is not removing as you have not added `class="hello"` to the `select` element in your html.

Comment: @TusharGupta What do you mean, add 5 selects by clicking "click here" link and then click remove on one button and it will remove *all* select lists, i don't think OP wants to remove every single select list he's added by one click

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.navoptions').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).prev().remove().end().remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QBqWP/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the SELECT object has been added dynamically, after the initial DOM creation, it is not associated with any listeners.[onClick in your case].

Like the others suggested, use ".on" to add a listener dynamically. You can find the related docs here. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".navoptions").on('click','.remove',function() {
        $(".hello").remove();
});
```

reference [On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)